# Is there a name for the theorem that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{n})^n < \infty$?

Tags: terminology, euler-mascheroni-constant

Is there a name for the theorem that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{n})^n < \infty$ ?
Wikipedia has a [List of things named after Leonhard Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_things_named_after_Leonhard_Euler#Euler's_theorems) which mentions Euler's number but not the theorem.

I wanted to write something like:

> Carleman's inequality can be proved using a weak form of Stirling's inequality, which follows from $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{n})^n < \infty$, which can be proved using Bernstein's inequality.

but that seems awkward.

Comment: it is $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=e$$ the Eulerian number.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Yes, but I am asking for the name of the theorem that $e < \infty$.

Comment: No. (To the question in the title and to the comment above.)

Comment: It might not have a particular name.

Comment: I call it 'Jimmhy'. Euler really should have given it a proper name.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a specific theorem for this. However, noticing that
$\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n=\lim_{n \to \infty}e^{n\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})}$=$e^{\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln(1+n^{-1})}{n^{-1}}}$

(because $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n>0$ and $y=e^x$ is differentiable for all x)

Then, it's obvious that the expression above could be simplified with L'Hopital's rule to get $e$ (However, L'Hopital's rule is not a theorem after all...And to argue this way we have to first define $e$ as a finite constant)

Answer (score -1):

The result $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{n})^n < \infty$ is a special case of the Monotone Convergence Theorem for sequences.

Comment: Why the downvote ????